# Using boost::push_relabel_max_flow

Tags: c++, graph, boost, max-flow, push-relabel

I am having trouble calculating the maximum flow for a given graph using boost::push_relabel_max_flow. I've written the following code:

```
std::map<Graph::edge_descriptor, long> edge2rescap;
boost::associative_property_map<std::map<Graph::edge_descriptor, long> > out(edge2rescap);
int flow_val = boost::push_relabel_max_flow (g_transformed_for_max_flow, v_start, v_end, capacity_map(boost::get(&EdgeProps::edge_capacity, g_transformed_for_max_flow))
                   .reverse_edge_map(boost::get(&EdgeProps::reverse_edge, g_transformed_for_max_flow))
                   .vertex_index_map(boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g_transformed_for_max_flow))
                   .residual_capacity_map(out));
```

The graph was defined as follows:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list_traits<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> Graph;
struct VertexProperty{ };
struct EdgeProps{
  // long edge_capacity;
  long edge_capacity;
  Graph::edge_descriptor reverse_edge;
  EdgeProps(long capacity, Graph::edge_descriptor reverseEdge): edge_capacity(capacity), reverse_edge(reverseEdge){};
  EdgeProps(long capacity):                                     edge_capacity(capacity){};
  EdgeProps(){};
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProperty, EdgeProps > DirectedGraph_maxflow;
typedef boost::graph_traits <DirectedGraph_maxflow>::edge_iterator edgeIt_dir;
typedef boost::graph_traits<DirectedGraph_maxflow>::out_edge_iterator out_edge_iterator;
```

My code compiles perfectly for my simple graph example. However, strangely it does so only if all capacities are chosen equally. If i change just one capacity the compiler outputs:  Assertion `algo.is_flow()' failed.

Maybe someone has had this issue once before and knows how to solve it. If not, it would be nice if someone of you could maybe share with me a small working example (using a non-trivial graph). Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: "the compiler outputs: Assertion"  Assertions are runtime errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without self-contained example, my best bet is you invoke [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the back edges are inconsistent?

Perhaps you can edit this **[Live Example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8986b3aad6548771)** to demonstrate the issue you're having:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/push_relabel_max_flow.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>

using Traits = boost::adjacency_list_traits<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS>;
using V      = Traits::vertex_descriptor;
using E      = Traits::edge_descriptor;
template <> struct fmt::formatter<E> : fmt::ostream_formatter {};
struct VertexProps {};

struct EdgeProps {
    long edge_capacity = 0;
    E    reverse_edge  = {};

    EdgeProps(long capacity = 0, E reverseEdge = {}) //
        : edge_capacity(capacity)
        , reverse_edge(reverseEdge){};
};

using Graph =
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProps, EdgeProps>;

int main() {
    Graph g(5);
    auto ecap = get(&EdgeProps::edge_capacity, g);
    auto reve = get(&EdgeProps::reverse_edge, g);

    auto insert = [&](V s, V t, EdgeProps p) {
        auto fwd  = add_edge(s, t, p, g).first;
        auto bck  = add_edge(t, s, {}, g).first;
        reve[fwd] = bck;
        reve[bck] = fwd;
    };

    insert(0, 1, {6});
    insert(1, 2, {7});
    insert(2, 3, {3});
    insert(3, 4, {1});
    V v_start = 1, v_end = 4;

    std::map<E, long> residuals;

    int flow_val = push_relabel_max_flow(
        g, v_start, v_end,
        capacity_map(ecap)
            .reverse_edge_map(reve)
            .residual_capacity_map(make_assoc_property_map(residuals)));

    fmt::print("flow: {} residuals: {}\n", flow_val, residuals);
}
```

Printing

> flow: 1 residuals: {(0,1): 6, (1,0): 0, (1,2): 6, (2,1): 1, (2,3): 2, (3,2): 1, (3,4): 0, (4,3): 1}

Comment: Thank you so much for your post! You were right about the back edges! My mistake was that i only initialized the reverse edge property for the edges of my main graph and didn't do it as well for the artificial back edges needed for the residual graph. I did this since in the official documentation it says: "the input graph should be $G_in = (V,{E \cup E^T})$. The ReverseEdgeMap argument rev must map each edge in the original graph to its reverse edge, that is $(u,v) \rightarrow (v,u) \forall (u,v) \in E$. ". (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/graph/doc/push_relabel_max_flow.html)

Comment: @CookieMonster98 Yeah, that's a tricky wording, and I just erred on the safe side. It makes sense that the algo cannot distinguish "original" edges from "artificial" edges if  you think about it (some back edges could be original!)

Comment: Yes it does make sense! Thank you once again! You saved me many more hours of wasted time :)